# How to handle message chaining in this situation

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, microservices, event-driven

I'm currently trying to figure out what would be the best approach to solving the following issue.

We are using a microservice architecture and in order for some product features to be enabled they require previous services to have finished their job.

In the example below `Service4` requires that `Service1` and `Service2` finish their tasks.

I was considering using an orchestration service which knew which service depended
on which and released the service messages in the correct order.

But I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this orchestration service and do it entirely using a choreographed saga?

```
              ┌────────┐
     ┌───────►│Service1├───────┐  
     │        └────────┘       ▼  
┌────┴────┐                ┌────────┐ 
│  Start  │                │Service4│  
└────┬────┘                └───▲────┘  
     │        ┌────────┐       │  
     └───────►│Service2├───────┘  
              └────────┘
```

My main concerns here are that `Service4` will have to keep record of every message it has received in a database and keep track whether all required messages for the task have been received and that the same logic will have to be reimplemented on every service which has multiple dependencies.

Comment: Some component has to keep track of the partial state. Orchestration service besides keeping the state gives great visibility into the overall business flow. It also supports features like cancellation and async updates to the transaction state which is extremely hard to do using choreography. Check out temporal.io for orchestration.

Comment: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the correct comment above by Maxim that **some** service has to own partial-state responsibility, I submit the following:

If `Service 1` and `Service 2` completing for some aggregated task is ONLY relevant to `Service 4` - i.e. it doesn't represent an actual functional process completing - then `Service-4` should be responsible for tracking the partial state.

If the fact those two services have completed has *some* standalone relevance - even if `Service 4` didn't exist - then it makes sense to have an Orchestration service of some sort to aggregate, implement rules, and generate new events.

If nobody except `Service-4` understands the rules in the above-mentioned Orchestration service, that's a good sign they should exist within `Service-4.`

**EDIT:** Since you've indicated `Service-4` is **NOT** the only service that cares about the fact that the other two services have completed, it absolutely makes sense to add what's (probably) more properly called a [Choreography](https://solace.com/blog/microservices-choreography-vs-orchestration/) Service.

There are a number of options, but in general I'd expect it to monitor for `Service-1` and `Service-2` to complete and generate a new event that `Service-4` will consume.

Comment: In our case `Service 4` is not the only one that requires that `Service 1` and `Service 2`, there are other services that also require that those tasks be done before proceeding. So I guess I was going in the right direction from the start?

Comment: Yep, you were on the right track!  Added a touch more info to my response for consideration.